# VSCode Remote-SSH with AWS Session Manager and AWS SSO (CLI): Permission denied (public key)

Tags: amazon-web-services, visual-studio-code, ssh, vscode-remote-ssh, aws-session-manager

I'm trying to access a private EC2 instance from a local Visual Studio Code IDE with Session Manager and AWS SSO (CLI). I have the following in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host i-0dXXXXXXXXXX
    User ubuntu
    ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "aws sso login --profile ExProfile; aws ssm start-session --target %h --profile ExProfile--document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
```

So when I try to connect to the EC2 via VSCode Remote-SSH, it begins the login process (via browser) for my AWS SSO account as expected, however, after I allow the request, it throws out an error: `ubuntu@i-0dXXXXXXXXXX: Permission denied (publickey).`

```
[23:52:21.763] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[23:52:21.769] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 63367 "i-0dXXXXXXXXXX" bash
[23:52:21.777] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[23:52:22.068] > ]0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[23:52:22.069] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[23:52:32.400] > The authenticity of host 'i-0dXXXXXXXXXX (<no hostip for proxy command>)' c
> an't be established.
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:gGuNpmbuoZFSyDD2utyHzp7IVV//OkM64AV+jBpBccU.    
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
[23:52:32.401] Detected fingerprint confirmation message
[23:52:32.401] Showing fingerprint confirmation dialog
[23:52:50.005] Got fingerprint response: yes
[23:52:50.006] "install" wrote data to terminal: "yes"
[23:52:50.029] > y
[23:52:50.045] > Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes        
> Warning: Permanently added 'i-0dXXXXXXXXXX' (ECDSA) to the list of known ho
> sts.
[23:52:50.216] > ubuntu@i-0dXXXXXXXXXX: Permission denied (publickey).
[23:52:50.310] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[23:52:51.613] "install" terminal command done
[23:52:51.614] Install terminal quit with output: ubuntu@i-0dXXXXXXXXXX: Permission denied (publickey).
[23:52:51.614] Received install output: ubuntu@i-0dXXXXXXXXXX: Permission denied (publickey).
[23:52:51.617] Resolver error: Error: Permission denied (publickey).
```

My understanding was that I wouldn't have to worry about SSH key pairs with AWS Session Manager, so why am I still getting this `publickey` error. Am I doing something wrong here? Any ideas on how to resolve this?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You still need a key to connect. Let me explain with a sample ssh config,

```
Host ip-xxx-109-xxx-11.vpc.internal
     User ssm-user
     IdentityFile "C:\Users\localuser\.ssh\ssm-user-i-xxxxx54fd41xxxxxx"
     ProxyCommand C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "aws ssm start-session --target i-xxxxx54fd41xxxxxx --profile remote-debug-profile --document-name AWS-StartSSHSession --parameters 'portNumber=%p'"
```

Whats happening here is,

VSCode treats `--target i-xxxxx54fd41xxxxxx` as a proxy ssh server (read, a tunnel server) to connect to the `Host ip-xxx-109-xxx-11.vpc.internal` as `User ssm-user`.

So it first establishes a connection to the host instance through the `ProxyCommand`. It then tries to ssh into the `Host` using the `User` provided. But guess what, it needs a key to do so. Thats where it uses the `IdentityFile`.

To make things easy, I did `ssh-keygen` on the remote ec2 instance, did `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and then copied the `~/.ssh/id_rsa` (private key) to local machine as `C:\Users\localuser\.ssh\ssm-user-i-xxxxx54fd41xxxxxx` to use in ssh key exchange. You can use different key pair if you want to.

The key point to note is, I baked the `--target i-xxxxx54fd41xxxxxx` into the proxy command, and made host name with `Host ip-xxx-109-xxx-11.vpc.internal`.

This is because, we cannot use `--target %h`, because session manager then will try to login to `ip-xxx-109-xxx-11.vpc.internal`, instead of using the instance id. Which we don't want!

Make sure the host name is correct (like `ip-xxx-109-xxx-11.vpc.internal`) so when VS Code issues the ssh tunnel it will try with `user@host` (like `ssm-user@ip-xxx-109-xxx-11.vpc.internal`).

I know its late, but hope it helps someone else, understanding the process and adjust it to their needs.